# why and how to retrieve user informations logged in with facebook on aws cognito?

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I would like to understand why when someone signIn with a federated identity, i can't find the user's informations in the aws console.

I've got a mobile application which is develop with react-native. I'm using the react-native-fbsdk and the aws-amplify librairies.

When user ask to signIn with facebook, i'm asking to facebook to get an AccessToken. When i got it, i'm asking to facebook to retrieve his "name, email" fields using the graph. Now i've got the accessToken and his expiration time, the email and the name of the facebook user.

Then, i'm asking to AWS Cognito to signIn his user using the accessToken, and i provide the name and email. Using the `Auth.federatedSignIn` method from aws-amplify. Cognito answer that the user is authenticated.

From here, i'm stuck. When i go to my aws console, i can't find the user's informations. I hoped to find almost his email and his name. I see that there is a logged user when i go to federated identities. But when i go to users and groups in the general settings of my cognito pool, i can't find the user. Ok, so i go to the groups and i see an autogenerated group for Facebook. But when i go here, again, i can't find the user.

In summary, i understand that my user is authenticated using facebook. But i've lost the 2 basics informations, his name and his email and i don't understand why i can't find this logged in user in the console (this is what i've expected finally) :/

Someone can explain me ?

Comment: I think you are simply using identity pool to sign in the user with facebook federated identity. If that is the case, then you won't see any reference of the user in the user pool. You have to create a mapping in user pool and let the user sign in with facebook to user pool if you want him added as registered user.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand "create a mapping in the user pool". I've mapped some attributes in the federated tabs (where you can configure all the attributes mapped for each oauth providers) and that's why i've expected to see them after.

Comment: Do you have some resources (videos, tutorials, etc) on how i could do it ? Because, from what i understand, i just authenticate the user to use some of my aws services but not really register it, isn't it ?

Comment: Did you do this in user pool or identity pool?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

When you use a indetity provider, may it be ADFS or Facebook , you donot have any user on the AWS side. The user and all the other user details reside on the authenticator side (AD or Facebook). On the AWS side, you only see the username that is used to login (generally an email ) and the IAM role.

IAM ROLE/user

IAM policies attached to this role govern the permission levels.

[screenshot of my user login from ADFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu9Ny.png)

If you login in without any federated service authentication, the only differnce will be that there will be a user under the aws IAM/users section wich can then be added in a IAM group. However in case of federated login, users and groups are maintained at the federation level.